# Why is my URL [object%20Object] in API call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, reactjs, redux

My render is below. I have run out of ideas.

```
class Settings extends Component {

  render(){
    return(
    <div className='App container'>
       <h3>Select Currency</h3>
      <select className="custom-select"
        onChange={(prop, attr) => this.props.fetchData(id,value)}>
        <option value='selected'></option>
        <option value='EUR'>EUR</option
      </select>
      <Link to='/' className="btn" type="submit">Submit</Link>
    </div>
  )
 }
}

}
```

Please help, what is wrong with my code? How can I solve this strange error?

Comment: use JSON.stringify(value)

Comment: It appears that `id` is an object, not a `string` or `int`...

Comment: What do you pass to fetchCurrency?

Comment: Share you code where you call fetchCurrency

Comment: I'm sure you pass `id` as string and your `fetchCurrency` use that with `getElementById()` (or similar) to get that element and its _currency value_, and when it returns it is an object instead (which the result clearly shows). What do you get if you use `fetch (CURRENCY+ '/' + id.id + ' /?convert=' + value)` ?

Comment: @LGSon, I get the same...

Comment: Well, obviously the `id` is an object and you need to follow that backwards to see where it gets assigned.

Comment: @LGSon Please check my edit.

Comment: @ArtemMirchenko, please check my edit.

Comment: @MathiasW, please check my edit.

Comment: @JohnSam Thanks, look at my answer, try and see what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your onChange handler incorrect because no `id` and `value` is passed to it, only event object. From event.target object you should get this values, here is example, and short refactor of your component:

```
class Settings extends Component {

  handleChange(e) {
   this.props.fetchCurrency(e.target.id, e.target.value)
  }


  render(){
    return(
     <div className='App container'>
      <h3>Select Currency</h3>
      <select className="custom-select" id="inputGroup"
       onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}>
       <option value='selected'></option>
       <option value='EUR'>EUR</option>
       <option value='AUD'>AUD</option>
       <option value='GBP'>GBP</option>
       <option value='CAD'>CAD</option>
       <option value='JPY'>JPY</option>
      </select>
     <Link to='/' className="btn btn-light btn-block" type="submit">Submit</Link>
  </div>
  )
 }
}
```

Comment: Perfect mate! Works like a charm. Only `id="inputGroup"` is obsolete, since he will take `id` from there. :)

Comment: Yes, you can set other attributes in select or get them from options, no problem, try to console all and you will see all options.

Answer (score -1):

onChange does by default callback with event (if you log id you'll see a Proxy object). So what you need to do is:

`{(event) => this.props.fetchCurrency(event.target.value, event.target.options[event.target.options.selectedIndex].id)}`

`event.target.options[event.target.options.selectedIndex].id` is needed if you want the selected option's ID - which for the time being seems absent in your code.